# how to position one div over the other ( with using relative positioning only )

Tags: css

I know there are many similar questions out there but i was not able to get a solution. I have a center-Logo for my webpage and im trying to place my webcontent over my centerlogo. I know this can be achievable by using absolute positioning of the center Logo. But for my design relative postioning works the best, and the center logo behaves the way i want it. Now the issue is that on relative positioning the content of the page comes below the center logo. Is there any solution to place mycontent above the  logo while using relative positioning ?

solutions i have tried , Z-index, postion:fixed and clear:both

```css
.center-logo{
  
  z-index:0;
  position:relative;
  top: 0;
  margin-left:130px;
  background:inherit;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.1;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
   filter: grayscale(100%);
 
}

 /*---------where the main content is-------*/
.mycontent{                     
  margin-top:4.75rem;
  margin-left: 4.375rem;
  z-index: 2;

}
```

```html
<div class = "center-logo">  
<img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" height="850" width="1000">  
</div> 

<div class="mycontent">

</div>
```

Comment: sharing your html as well will probably help

Comment: hey @Anonymouse I have added the html.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways

**1- use your logo as a background for your content**

**2- add negative margin-top to align your content over the logo**

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your "div.center-logo" and add the image as background-image (background-position:center, background-size:contain) to "div.mycontent".

```
div.mycontent {
   background-image: url(images/logo2.png); /* check this url */
   background-position:center;
   background-size:contain;
}
```